# RAID for a video streaming server

Tags: linux, raid

I need to build a video streaming server with only 4 harddisk, the performance is more important than the disk space.

Wondering which RAID should I implementing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raid 0 and Raid 10 offer the best performance.  Raid 0 however can not tolerate any drive failures - so be sure you have backups in case a drive fails (which is a good idea anyways).

Comment: I will go with raid 10, thanks Grant